# C++ expiration mechanism in a c++ class

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

We have a new requirement to call an http service using an authorization
token. So in order to get the "result" we need to do this in two steps.
First make an http call to get the authorization token from an auth server
and then using the token make the second http to get the "result" (passing
the auth token in the header).

We need to enhance this "simple" two http calls model, since we can reuse
the auth token for some time, eg 5 minutes. So we can call the auth server
to take the token and renew the token in 5 minutes and so on.

We want to have that in one C++ class so from our main function to do this

```
//main.cpp

Authorization auth_obj; //global
int main(...)
{
    auth_obj::initialize(); //call a static function

    process_loop(); //for ever
}

process_loop() {

    select(...) {
        details = auth_obj->get_auth_details();

        http->add_header(details);
        "result" = http->getResult();

    }

}

//Authorization.cpp

class Authorization {

    details_t auth_details_;
    get_auth_details( return auth_details_;)
    initialize(){

        auth_details = http->get_token_from_server();
        save(auth_details)
        renew(5 minutes);
    }

    save(auth_details) { auth_details = auth_details}

    renew(time argument) {
        //blocks here for 5 minutes
    }
}
```

The problem with this pseudocode above is that when we call initialize, the execution will block in Authorization::renew(...).

What we need is to call initialize, take the first token and after 5 minutes the authorization class instance to automatically renew the token and wait there for the next 5 minutes and so on.

What is the proper way to do this? boost::async, boost::threads, std::threads? Is there any example?

Comment: You might have more luck asking this on [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I was looking for a proper solution in here, using for exampe threads or boost::async

Comment: In that case I suggest you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41651992/edit) the question to include the relevant information.

Comment: @cateof Well, you have a wrong model, so 1st you need to get the model right, then implement it. I still see two loopholes in your description. You want to renew the token once every 5 minutes? Or every time for 5 minutes. You code suggest the latter, your words the former. If you want to renew a 5 min token exactly after 5 minutes, you are risking missing the deadline. From my experience, usually, each time you use a token it automatically gets extented lifetime, so you don't have to do this manually, but the stale tokens do not stay on the serer side. Your case seems to be different. Is it?

Comment: @luk32 I want to get a new token every five minutes. I agree, needs to be updated a little bit earlier, but as you said the server offers the time validity of the token. That will be the decision of the next renewal, however I just wanted to simplify here.

Comment: @RawN when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Good to know. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two approach on what you want to achieve.

1. if you don't want to involve multi-threading. You can add a `Timer` in your `Authorization` class, the timer will expire in 5 mins, check if the token is expired before send your request.
2. Using another thread to update token every 5 mins. In this case you can use `std::thread` and create your thread to update token like this:

   ```
   class Authorization
   {
   public:
       Authorization() = default;
       ~Authorization()
       {
           token_update_thread.detach();
       }

       details_t get_auth_details()
       {
           std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(token_lock);
           return auth_details_;
       }

       void initialize()
       {
           token_update_thread = std::move(std::thread([this]()
           {
               while (true) {
                   renew();
                   std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                       std::chrono::minutes(5));
               }
           }));
       }

       void renew()
       {
           std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(token_lock);
           // do whatever you need to update auth_details_
       }

       std::mutex token_lock;
       details_t auth_details_;
       std::thread token_update_thread;
   };
   ```

Comment: Upvoted for sleeping for `5min` as opposed to `300000ms` (or some other unreadable unit of time).